# "Who is God" or "What is God"?

Tags: word-choice, who, what

Which is correct: "Who is God?" or "What is God?"
In my opinion God is "who", but I've just seen a billingual book with a title "What is God?" and I got confused.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of context? "What is God?" maybe like: What is God made of? Just an illusion? Metaphysics?
"Who is God?'' might already have personified the (abstract) idea of (a) God and asks about that.

Comment: Ok, so you can name a book for children "What is God"? Am I right?

Comment: Hello, Umka. This is not a question of which English works, as that depends on one's ideas about God. But it does seem strange to me that people can have a concept of God that doesn't recognise that a God less than human in any way (non-sentient, or even not a person) seems a contradiction in terms.

Comment: You could try https://christianity.stackexchange.com, https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/, https://islam.stackexchange.com/, or https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/ for this (not sure if that's every religion-based SE site)

Comment: This is a question of theology, not English.

Comment: 'it depends'...!

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference here lies in treating God as a concept or an entity.

"What is God?" questions the concept of a higher being and requests a holistic explanation, whereas "Who is God?" asks to identify the being known as 'God'. Existence is not doubted in the latter case.

So neither are 'correct'' as they are questioning entirely different things.

Edit: in retrospect, I should say neither are incorrect. Both questions are justifiable, the only situation in which they would be wrong is to use one in place of the other as their meanings differ

Comment: Of course equally, neither is "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

This question borders on philosophy and theology, but not knowing if migration is really appropriate, I thought it was worth offering an answer here.

I think it is useful to compare the question to each of the following:

1. What is gravity?
2. Who is the president?
3. What is Umka?
4. Who is Umka?

The first question asks about the nature of gravity. What sort of a thing is it? Is it even appropriate to refer to gravity as a "thing"? This is a reasonable sort of question which could also be asked about God.

The second question considers a role and asks who is the current role holder. "God" is sometimes thought of as a title in a similar fashion, but it would be odd to use the question in that way as a title for a book.

The third question is about you. It asks what sort of a thing you are. To sensitive types this question sounds offensive. (I hope you are not offended.) It raises the possibility that Umka might not be a person but something less or at least "other" than that. Of course I believe you are a person, and "a person" or "a human" would be a good initial answer to the question. Nonetheless, someone who had not yet met you might genuinely not know. In some circumstances it might be reasonable to ask what Umka is; is Umka a fictional construct, an advanced form of artificial intelligence, a living breathing human or something else? Moreover, to an alien species, even the answer "a human person" may need significant elaboration as to what being a human person involves. Similarly, in response to the question "What is God?" It is possible to give both short and long answers which attempt to explain what kind of thing God is (or is considered to be).

The fourth question assumes that Umka is a person (although questions about what kind may remain open) and asks for more information about them. Ukma is the person who did X, and is Y, and likes Z. Asking a similar question of God avoids the possibility of offense that many perceive in the third type of question. Nevertheless, there is a very large overlap between what may be considered an answer to the third question and what may be considered an answer to the fourth question ... especially if God (or for that matter Umka) is not a "normal" person.

I hope you have to been offended by raising the (purely theoretical) possibility of your not being human. I use your name mostly because it seemed the easiest way to convey the possibility of offense in such questions, and obviously people can be very sensitive about religious matters and those who (supposedly) offend God.

I think by considering the questions above you can see that either form of the question could be correct, but that they may suggest somewhat different starting points for the discussion.

As a bonus: Orthodox Christians accept the doctrine of the Trinity, according to which God is not *a* person, but *three* person_s_, while mysteriously also being *one substance*. A nice way to express this which overlaps with your question is to say that God is three "whos" and one "what". You might even think that a Christian should consider the proper form of the question to be "Who *are* God?", but I don't think anyone would recommend that!